# Why does exec command is not working on TCL?

Tags: linux, tcl

I´m pretty new in TCL. I made a script with the following code:

```
if {[file exists /proc/cpuinfo]} {
  exec grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
  exec grep "cpu MHz"    /proc/cpuinfo
}

puts "Hostname : [info hostname]"
```

For some reason, the exec command is not executed. Even if I take out the brackets, the command is not working.
Besides, if I execute command by command in tclsh, it works correctly.

```
tclsh
%exec grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name :Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU    @2.53GHz
%exec grep "cpu MHz" /proc/cpuinfo
cpu MHz    :2533.423
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with what `exec` returns...

Answer (score 2):

I'll expand a little on what Shawn rightly wrote, since this behavior is quite unexpected for someone new to `tclsh` (like me), although it is explained by these words in the [`exec` manual page](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm#M21):

> If standard output has not been redirected then the **exec**
> command returns the standard output from the last command …

It notably says *returns*, which doesn't mean that it's printed, but rather it's discarded if we don't do something with the output, like passing it to `puts` like you did with `[info hostname]`:

```
  puts [exec grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo]
  puts [exec grep "cpu MHz"    /proc/cpuinfo]
```

We get away without `puts` in interactive mode because the command result there is printed automatically.